# haskell could not find module Data MemoTrie

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to follow the http://www.yellosoft.us/evilgenius/ haskell tutorial, but this code does not work:

```
  1 import Data.MemoTrie (memo)
  2 
  3 fib :: Int -> Int
  4 fib = memo fib'
  5     where
  6         fib' :: Int -> Int
  7         fib' 0 = 0
  8         fib' 1 = 1
  9         fib' n = fib' (n-1) + fib' (n-2)
 10         
 11 main :: IO ()
 12 main = do
 13     putStrLn $ show $ fib 30
```

I'm getting the error when trying to compile it:

> fib2.hs:1:8:
>
> ```
>   Could not find module `Data.MemoTrie'
> ```

I'm obviously a newbie, so I don't know how to find out if it's been removed or renamed or something. What do I need to do it make the code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the necessary [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie):

```
cabal install memotrie
```